# Как осуществить рекурсивный вызов функции без использования ее имени

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Существует множество функций одного типа FI, где I- число и индекс функции, например:

```
byte F5( byte COMMAND );
byte F3456( byte COMMAND );
```

Функция выполняет действия в соответствии с командой `COMMAND`.
На команду `COMMAND_ID` функция возвращает свой индекс `I`.

Вопрос:
Как вызвать функцию рекурсивно, не используя ее имя ( FI() )?
Возможно, как-то через this?

Благодарю.

Comment: а можно узнать, с чем связано ограничение на использование имени ф-ии ?

Comment: Сложить указатели в массив и вызывать по индексу - это не оно?

Comment: Не оно. Именно, интересует рекурсивный вызов функции самой из себя без указания имени. Думал, что в c++ это возможно. Функций много, т.к. фактически каждая функция - это уникальный алгоритм. В целях отладки, в firmware прошивается сразу множество алгоритмов и происходит их переключение в динамике. Индекс функции - это уникальный индекс алгоритма.

Comment: Алгоритм может вызывать сам себя. Очень неудобно, как в случае с отладочным выводом (в котором указывается индекс алгоритма), так и в случае с рекурсивным вызовом, использовать конкретное имя функции. GOTO здесь бы помогло :)

Comment: Такое можно провернуть с функторами. `struct Foo{void operator()(){ (*this)();}};`

Comment: Интересная реализация FSM...

Comment: Пока решил некрасиво с помощью `#define fi() F.()` в начале функции, использованием `fi()` в теле и `#undef fi` в конце.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, будьте добры, помогите ссылкой, где поучиться вашей идее. Проект пишется для микроконтроллеров, поэтому классов избегаю для увеличения быстродействия.  Конечно же, с классами было бы удобнее, но мощности не те. Сейчас пробую организовать внутри функции внешний цикл, чтобы выходить в него для рекурсивного запуска тела функции. Посмотрим, что получится.

Comment: @Osetroff, я даже не знаю что вам посоветовать. Можете погуглить "*Функторы C++*". Тут основная идея в том, чтобы использовать объекты как функции за счет перегрузки `operator()()`. Обычно это используется, когда функциональный объект нужно куда-то передать, как альтернатива указателями на фунцию(весь stl этим пронизан вдоль и поперек). Есть у этого подхода свои преимущества, иногда даже по эффективности